# elb + auto scaling on aws Nginx + .net core web-api

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core-webapi, scaling, auto, aws-elb

I am newbie to aws load balancing.  Currently,  I got 504 error and 502 error from elb when I  run load testing.  Normally, my api response less than 1 sec but when I  run concurrent 2000 threads for 10 to 30 mins response time is steady growing up to 1 min after all my threads are clear.  I checked CPU utilization of instances under auto scaling group and all instances CPU are less than 50 percentage.  I also checked the monitoring under target group and elb. 5xx error are shown.  I don't know why my instances are responding 5xx error to elb.  All health checked status are OK.  That's concern with Nginx or. Net core runtime?

Comment: I found two main problems of my post. First one is MySQL connection are closed and didn't disposed [MySQL still open with timeout] (Too Many Connection error in Instances). Second one is Nginx reach it max_woker limit. Now both are solved.